# Database using Visual Studio C# (Web Application)

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, web-applications

I have to create implement a database in one of my projects.
I'm using Visual Studio and coding in C#
The problem I'm experiencing is that I cannot find information on how to create a database with a web application as well as which database program would be best to use.

Any documentation explaining how to go about making and using the database will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sign up to Windows Azure. You get a free trial and a nice GUI to create databases and web apps.

Then you can use some basic SQL to start interacting with the database

Answer (score 0):

Sql databases are much easier to use with Visual studio.

Following articles could help you get started with that.

[SQL Server Database Development in Visual Studio](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825831/SQL-Server-Database-Development-in-Visual-Studio)

**EDIT:** After comment about OP the following link could be helpful.

[How to: Access SQL Server Using Predetermined Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds20z471.aspx)

Comment: content in the link may change, so add content with the answer

Comment: Those are good for making the database but what I really need is how to use it in a C# Web Application.

Comment: For that you can use Entitiy Framework, or ADO.NET. @ZaheerMoola

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: - Look at the answer provided Here [Add new table to EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786140/add-new-table-to-ef)**

Look into *entity framework* and how to create a database, there are 3 ways you can create a database for web applicaitons, the typical workflows are:

- Database First
- Model First
- Code First

For more information you can look at the tutorial videos for building applications with `MVC 4`:

[Developing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Applications Jump Start](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start-8239) - Microsoft

[Building Applications with ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mvc4-building) - Pluralsight

Answer (score 0):

I guess i may have been a bit vague in what I wanted but thanks nonetheless to everyone who helped put me on the right track. I've got the basic connection down and am currently working through different queries.